# The overloaded operator<< template doesn't work for std::list, although it does for std::vector

Tags: c++, templates

By means of a template, I overloaded operator<< so that it outputs all the elements of a container:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> typename C>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const C<T>& con) { for (const T& e : con) o << e; return o; }
```

It works OK with `std::vector`s, but it produces an error message when I attempt to apply it to a `std::list`:

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka
>   std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘std::__cxx11::list’)   cout <<
>   li;

Here's is my code excerpt (compiled on GCC 5.2.1, Ubuntu 15.10):

```
#include "../Qualquer/std_lib_facilities.h"

struct Item {

    string name;
    int id;
    double value;

    Item(){};
    Item(string n, int i, double v):
        name{n}, id{i}, value{v} {}
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Item& i) { return is >> i.name >> i.id >> i.value; }
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Item& it) { return o << it.name << '\t' << it.id << '\t' << it.value << '\n'; }

template<typename T, template<typename> typename C>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const C<T>& con) { for (const T& e : con) o << e; return o; }


int main()
{
    ifstream inp {"../Qualquer/items.txt"};
    if(!inp) error("No connection to the items.txt file\n");

    istream_iterator<Item> ii {inp};
    istream_iterator<Item> end;
    vector<Item>vi {ii, end};
    //cout << vi;//this works OK
    list<Item>li {ii, end};
    cout << li;//this causes the error
}
```

However, when I write a template specifically for the `std::list`, it works OK:

```
template<typename T> 
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const list<T>& con) { for (auto first = con.begin(); first != con.end(); ++first) o << *first; return o; }
```

Why does the `ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const C<T>& con)` template turns out to be inapplicable to `std::list`?

Comment: as far as I can see your template operator takes containers that takes only one template parameter `template<typename> typename C` as such both `std::vector` and `std::list` shouldn't match

Comment: This is Bjarne's teaching header, right? He has a `template <class T> class Vector` and a `#define vector Vector`. @W.F.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, the header file is Bjarne's teaching header from his site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<typename T, template<typename> typename C>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const C<T>& con) { for (const T& e : con) o << e; return o; }
```

Why so complicated? You need type name `T` only to use it in your for loop. You may as well get it through `C::value_type` or just use `auto` keyword:

```
template<typename C>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const C& con)
{
    for (const typename C::value_type& e : con) o << e; return o;
}

template<typename C>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const C& con)
{
    for (auto& e : con) o << e; return o;
}
```